# Esami: Formatting the exam exercises

Tags: formatting, exam, esami

I posted a question recently about probsoln but since have tried to move my exam to the esami package as it seems more powerful and what I want. However, I've struggled a bit to modify the example to what I'm wanting. Currently, my (pre-probsoln / pre-esami) exams look like this:

[image]

It's a bit important to me that they have this format as I'm using mastery based grading and would like the exercises to be listed by the learning outcomes I have listed. Currently, the esami package is generating the examples like this:

[image]

1. For the life of me I can't figure out how to change the format of this to look like how I want. The "Exercise 1" is not what I want here. I tried looking in the documentation but couldn't see another option of exercise that worked here. So I guess I'd be okay with completely erasing the "Exercise 1" that esami is generating since I'll be manually writing these.
2. Also, sometimes when I re-compile, the exercises randomize, which is nice. But I'm wondering how do I fix the seed? I couldn't make sense of this with the documentation. I'd eventually like to make an exam version and then a solution version, but I'd need to guarantee the same seed to do that.

Files:

```
\RequirePackage{currfile}

\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[shufflerandom,xyz,autopstoff,twocolumns,fillb,solutionsonly]{esami}%%%%% TEMA
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{The name of the exam}
\def\numcompiti{4}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2013/3/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT AAAA/M/D
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading
%\def\cartella{d:/folder}%%% The folder where are the exercises: by default the current folder%

\geometry{margin=0.5in}

\newcommand*{\myTitleName}{}
\newcommand*{\setmyTitleName}{%
  \edef\myTitleName{\currfilebase}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\setmyTitleNameaux
    \expandafter\myTitleName\expandafter"\myTitleName"\relax
}
\newcommand*{\setmyTitleNameaux}{}
\def\setmyTitleNameaux#1"#2"#3\relax{\def\myTitleName{#2}}
\setmyTitleName

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\alph{enumi})}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \huge \myTitleName  \\ % Title is the same as the file name.
 \large Tuesday, November $19^{\textrm{th}}$, 2020 \\ %Adjust the date of exam
% \flushleft \large Name:
\end{center}

\testversioni
\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
% +=============================+
% |       THE SEED              |
% +=============================+

%\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
%%% OR SOME OTHER LIKE
\FPeval\seme{round(\thenomefile*(\thevers)+1-trunc(\thenomefile*(\thevers)/(2^31-1):0)*(2^31-1):0)}
%\FPeval\seme{round(1+abs(\thenomefile/(\thevers)+sin(\thevers)*(\thevers)^(2)):0)}

\permuta
% +=============================+
% |  STUFF DEFINED IN CFG FILE  |
% +=============================+

Instructions: Make sure to clearly show your work on each problem. If there's not enough work or steps, you may not receive a pass due to the lack of work. Make sure to follow the directions or you may not earn points toward mastery of the outcome! \textbf{Be sure to box your answer. It is possible to not pass a problem due to boxing something that is not an answer, so be careful!}

\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Add: PC1* - Completely factor the polynomial (over \textbf{the real numbers}):
%a) 
\esercizi{PS1A}

%b) 
%\esercizi{PS1B}
\newpage
                                                                       %
                                                                %
\setcounter{page}{1} %%% dvi
}
\end{document}
```

Problems:

```
\newproblem{
\begin{problem}
\FPsetpar{a}{3}{10}
a) $\displaystyle p(x) = \a$
\begin{solution}

\end{solution}
\end{problem}
}

\newproblem{
\begin{problem*}[4]\estraialfa{4}{a,b,c,x,y,z}{element}Let $A=\{\elementi,\elementii,\elementiii\}$ and $B=\{\elementi,\elementiii,\elementiv\}$.
\begin{parts}
\item \PTs{2}
List (without repetition) the elements of the set $A\cup B$
\begin{solution}[3cm]
\[A \cup B=\left\{\elementi,\elementii,\elementiii,\elementiv\right\}\]
\end{solution}
\begin{workarea}{3cm}
$A \cup B=$
\end{workarea}
\item \PTs{2}
List (without repetition) the elements of the set $A\cap B$
\begin{solution}[3cm]
\[A \cap B=\left\{\elementi,\elementiii\right\}\]
\end{solution}
\begin{workarea}{3cm}
$A \cap B=$
\end{workarea}
\end{parts}
\end{problem*}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is what I'm seeing now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the exercise name you can try these:

```
\renewcommand\exlabel{name of exercise}
\newcommand\exlabelsol{name of exercise in the solutions}
\newcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel\ \theex@no.}} %% Format of the exercise name if the exercise is not divided into parts
\newcommand\exlabelformatwp{{\scshape\exlabel\ \theex@no.}}%% Format of the exercise name if the exercise is not divided into parts
```

To fix the seed:

```
\FPeval\seme{fixed number} %

\randomi=\seme %you must add this string to your code anyway
```

Please note that text and solutions are always equal if you choose a seed which depends only on the date and the version of the exam (the default behaviour).

EDIT: to change the name of each exercise you can use the following code:

```
\renewcommand\exlabel{your label}
```

to change the name of every exercise contained in an `\exercise` command or

```
\newproblem{\renewcommand\exlabel{your label}
```

if you want to change the name of each exercise itself

EDIT 2: to fix the number issue, you can use this code

In the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel\theex@no}}
\renewcommmand\exlabelformatwp{{\scshape\exlabel\theex@no\ }} 
\makeatother
```

In the exercise code (inside newproblem or, better, before the `\esercizi` command)

```
\renewcommand\exlabel{your choice}
```

EDIT 3:
If you want to automatically have something like
PS1
PS2
PS3
...

you must use `\exlabel{PS}` and in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel\theex@no}}
\renewcommand\exlabelformatwp{{\scshape\exlabel\theex@no\ }} 
\makeatother
```

Otherwise you can use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel}}
\renewcommand\exlabelformatwp{{\scshape\exlabel\ }} 
\makeatother
```

without `\theex@no`

The `\exlabel` command defines the exercise name
The `\exlabelformat` command defines how the name must be written. If you want the number you must put `\theex@no` otherwise not.

`ex@no` is a latex counter so if you want an automatic numbering such as
PS1A
PS1B
PS1C
...
you can use

```
\renewcommand\exlabelformat{{\scshape\exlabel\Alph{ex@no}\}}
\renewcommand\exlabelformatwp{{\scshape\exlabel\Alph{ex@no}\ }}
```

Comment: Also will that change the format to all be the same? If I want some to be called PS1... PS6... and others to be IF1...IF6... could I have the name be completed deleted or something? Different outcomes have different labels depending on their category.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Deleted a previous comment as I got it to partially work. But still wasn't able to get the pieces to work or remove the name and number altogether. (Could put it in the problem itself.)

Comment: @Ecoi, please see the edit of the post.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a ton. But I see get the "1" after I rename it. For example, if I use: "\renewcommand\exlabel{PS1A}", it shows; "PS1A 1. <problem>" The "1." number that's occurring is something I want to eliminate or somehow adjust. I have outcomes that go from PS1 - PS6 and then IF1 - IF6 and so on. I'd like to label them that way without numbering them like a traditional exam.

Comment: @Ecoi please see EDIT 2 in the original answer

Comment: You can also add the code for the preamble in the config file (xxx.cfg), which should be renamed differently. In this case, you should avoid the "\makeatletter" and "\makeatother" commands.

Comment: I edited the bottom of my post to show you what I'm seeing. The dot disappears from the first command, but the number persists still. Sorry to keep bothering you. Thank you so much for your help =).

Alternatively, is there a way to reset the counter? I could work around that too if eliminating the number becomes troublesome. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ecoi, in EDIT 3 I added a reply to your last question. If you have any other problem, I suggest you use our email contained in the package documentation.